# Realm DB - maximum number of records for react-native app

Tags: react-native, realm

I have a react-native app that is on a private store.
The users will not always have Internet access, but need access to about 50 million records.
These records change at a rate of maybe 100 per minute.

I was looking to solve this using Realm in "offline first", syncing it from a mongodb as the source in the cloud.

1. Is this a viable option or is there a better approach?
2. Can a realm DB in a react-native handle that much data with performance?

Also, bear in mind our native DB is SqlServer. So even if I use this approach, I have to get the data out of SqlServer first and into Mongo. Not ideal, but the only other approach I can think of would be to write an API that the app calls for a manual list of changes from SqlServer and write the sync logic myself. But sql-lite doesnt seem up to the job in holding that much data.

Comment: Opinion type questions are not well suited for SO; without knowing the entire use case answers would be guesswork. It's best to stick with coding specific questions as that's what SO is for. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For example "50 million records" sounds like a lot - however, if each record has a persons name and age, it really isn't that much. However, if each record contained blob data (not recommended) and occupied the full 16M limit, that's a lot of data.

Comment: Some info: Realm is always offline first - that's it's nature. It will sync in the background (if using FlexSync) at some point thereafter. Realm can pretty easily handle 50 million 'records' but how will depend on the configuration of your models and the device it runs on. Realm results are lazily loaded - meaning massive datasets can be handled without overloading the device. Quick math though; if each record is 16Mb, and there are 50 million of them, thats about 800 Tb of storage. A general desktop class computer (let alone a mobile device) would be challenged to store that much data.

Comment: Thank you Jay this helps. I guess I was more interested in the factual "will it work" vs opinions, but you have given me a good direction to use Realm. I calculate an average record will be 1000 bytes, so with 50mil customers it will be 50gb. So yes our agents will need to have top-end phones that are dedicated to this app.

Comment: That seems a like a LOT of data to be contained on a device - the use case may require it but this is a situation where Flexible Sync (instead of full/partition sync) really comes into play - it only stores and sync's the data the queries may run against.